# Cogs Not Working and not detected In Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My bot program can't detected cogs file
I have tried every way to solve it, but still nothing has changed

main.py

```
import discord
import os


from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

            
bot.run('MTA2NzQ1MDMxMTAzMzIzMzUxOA.GSdg-i.CW3X5T82VYGYjPqEPWZ8YQ6oDZni33T-Bi1Ovo')
```

lab.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class lab(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('lab.py is running')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def holla(ctx):
       await ctx.reply('hai')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(lab(bot))
```

[eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DIHJ.png)

Comment: Do not share your token on the internet. Please consider regenerating one in discord developer portal

Comment: Never put error text as an image to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never *calling* that `load()` function... It's cool that you made it, but if you're not using it then it's not very surprising that your cogs aren't  being loaded.

The recommended place to do this in is `setup_hook`. Subclass `Client` (or `Bot` depending on what you want) and override it.